# Add words after string and auto space in php

Tags: php

My PHP code is:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text = $_GET['name']"The text should be here" ;
$image_url="dump/".rawurlencode(trim($text)).".jpg";

// Check if the file doesn't exist, create it
if (!file_exists($image_url)) {   
    $jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('Desert.jpg');
    $white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 73, 41, 236);
    $font_path = 'OpenSans-Italic.TTF';
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 50, $white, $font_path, $text);
    imagejpeg($jpg_image,$image_url);
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);
 }

 readfile($image_url);
?>
```

My first problem is as that I'm getting the input from an HTML file and set the text on an image. I tried using `$_GET['name']`. After that I want to add some text which is fixed and should be displayed after the name. Also, if the name is too long, then it should automatically set its path.

The second problem I'm facing is: suppose I have written a long paragraph and it should be displayed on the image and my image size is only `713x400`, then how would I put an automatic enter so that the text automatically continues on the next line?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unclear. 1. what _is_ the _first_ question? 2. what do you mean by "in the next and the next so on" ?

Comment: *Getting input from a html file* is quite interesting however, even beside of that you already have answer for the first question in your code. It proves only that you make no effort to resolve the problem by yourself.

Comment: I have tried to add text as show in the coding but that doesn't work

Comment: I know. Read the code you have and learn what it does.

Comment: How to change the line if the words are much longer and going beyond the image size